# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: „Acces is denied”

Tags: c#, exception

I'm getting this exception in this function. Weirdly today everything worked fine until now. I didn't change anything in the code

```
static IntPtr GetModuleAddress(string name)
{
    Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo");

    foreach (ProcessModule mod in p[0].Modules)
    {
        if (mod.ModuleName == name)
        {
            return mod.BaseAddress;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Module not found!");              
}
```

No idea what causes this problem...

Comment: No, that is not unusual for a multi-player game like Counter Strike.  The developers constantly release updates with countermeasures against players cheating and ruining the fun for everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of reasons this could happen, probably the most likely is

- Running at the wrong permission level, *try a running at a more elevated level*.
- (This is speculative) but it could be a bitness issue, 32bit/64bit

Also if its throwing a Win32Exception it has a property called `NativeErrorCode` which will give you the actual `Win32Api` `ErrorCode` and other useful information

```
try
{
   // your code
}
catch(Win32Exception w) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(w.Message);
   Console.WriteLine(w.ErrorCode.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(w.NativeErrorCode.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine(w.StackTrace);
   Console.WriteLine(w.Source);
   Exception e= w.GetBaseException();
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```